# R: Finding the intersect of two lines

Tags: r

I have this simple code that creates 3 matrices and plots them:

```
Y=matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=1)
X1=matrix(c(2,3,3.5,4.5))
X2=matrix(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 1.1), nrow=1)
#Plotting
plot(X1, Y)+lines(X1,Y)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(X2, Y)+lines(X2,Y) + abline(v=0.4, col="red")
```

And here is the plot: 
[image]

Now, I want for the `X` value `0.4` to get all the `Y` values. The Y values are the values where the red line crosses the other two lines. 
So there should be two values, one value `Y1` for one line and the other `Y2` value for the other line.

Is there maybe any function that I could use to do this? I would really appreciate any suggestion how to do this.

Comment: Doesn't the x-axis value ordering seem a bit odd? Looks like your X1 values never go below x=2 so there's no value at 0.4 really. Maybe you can clean up with example a bit to make it a bit more clear what you're rally trying to do.

Comment: Please edit your code. `plot(X1, Y)+lines(X1,Y) + abline(v=0.4, col="red")` does not make sense.

Comment: My idea would be to find for `Xi`, `ai; bi` s.t. `ai <= 0.4 <= bi`, then compute the intersection between the line `y = 0.4` and the line generated by the segment `[ai, bi]`. However, as indicated above, something is odd about `X1`.

Comment: Please google "intersection between lines R" and show us your attempts. Cheers

Comment: @MrFlick I'm trying to find the Y values where `X1=0.4` and `X2=0.4` so the Y value for X1=0.4 should be approximately 2.4 and for X2=0.4 the Y value should be approximately 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the two graphs use different x scales, this is a rather odd question. Getting the crossing point for the X2 line is easy, but the X1 line is a little more complicated.

```
## X2 line
AF2 = approxfun(X2, Y)
AF2(0.4)
[1] 2.5
```

The problem with the X1 line is that 0.4 on your graph means only X2=0.4, but X1 != 0.4.  You can see that the 0.4 mark is half way between X1 = 2.5 and X1= 3, so we need to compute that value using X1 = 2.75.

```
AF1 = approxfun(X1, Y)
AF1(2.75)
[1] 1.75
```

Confirm with graph:

```
#Plotting
plot(X1, Y)+lines(X1,Y) + abline(v=0.4, col="red")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(X2, Y)+lines(X2,Y) 
abline(v=0.4)
points(c(0.4,0.4), c(1.75, 2.5), pch=20, col="red")
```

[image: Crazy Graph]

Answer (score 3):

`identify()` can be used to locate points in a scatter plot by clicking with the mouse in the plot area. Hope this is what you're looking for. Check it out!