# Finding the intersect of two lines in R

Tags: r, graph

I have some code which plots two lines from a set of points.
I need to find the intersect of the two.

```
red <- read.table("red.txt", header=TRUE) #Get's table
mag <- red$T #T values
outer <- red$O #outer values
inner <- red$I #inner values
plot(outer, mag) #plot outer points
abline(lm(mag~outer)) #line of best fit 
abline(inner, mag) #add inner line
```

It produces a graph[image] which is similar to what I want.
(I am aware it is not the most stylish). How can I find the coordinates of the lines crossing?

(sorry about the dodgy probably disgusting code I am just learning how to use it)

Comment: Check out the options at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521261/r-finding-the-intersect-of-two-lines?rq=1

Comment: @AutenticSporks I was struggling to work out how to apply it to my code but I will re go over it

Comment: Can you share some of your data using `dput(red)`?

Comment: structure(list(T = c(152L, 288L, 412L, 544L, 669L, 763L, 829L, 
877L), O = c(0L, 0L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 19L), I = c(59L, 
56L, 51L, 48L, 43L, 40L, 38L, 37L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L)) @LMc got it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this system of equations as @SteveM said using some linear algebra, which is done below using the `solve` function.

1. `lm` gives you the coefficients for the line of best fit you just have to store it, which is done below in the object `fit`.
2. You have coded the slope and intercept for your other line. The slope that you are plotting is `mag[1]` and the intercept is `inner[1]`. Note: you are passing `abline` the vectors `mag` and `inner`, but this function takes single values so it is only using the first element of each vector.
3. Using the form `mx - y = -b` put the `x` and negated `y` coefficients into a matrix `A`. These coefficients are `m` and `-1` for `x` and `y`. Put their negated intercepts into a vector `b`.
4. The output of `solve` will give you the `x` and `y` values (in that order) where the two lines intersect.

```
fit <- lm(mag~outer)
plot(outer, mag) #plot outer points
abline(fit) #line of best fit 
abline(inner[1], mag[1]) #add inner line

A <- matrix(c(coef(fit)[2], -1,
              mag[1], -1), byrow = T, nrow = 2)

b <- c(-coef(fit)[1], -inner[1])
(coord <- solve(A, b))
[1]   1.185901 239.256914

points(coord[1], coord[2], col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So helpful

Answer (score 1):

Generate the equations of the lines from the slope/intercept (m/b) regression outputs.  So

```
reg1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1)
reg2 <- lm(y2 ~ x2)
```

Provide the slopes (m1, m2) and the intercepts (b1, b2)

y1 = m1x1 + b1

y2 = m2x2 + b2

Since x1 = x2 = x and y1 = y2 = y then

m1x - y = -b1

m2x - y = -b2

You can solve the equations for the x,y unknowns.

Comment: How do I generate equations of lines?

Comment: See the update with the base R regression function.

Comment: Thank you ! That's really helped me