# find intersection of two lines-one linear and one nonlinear r

Tags: r

I would like to find the x value where RRpm = y2

```
SSpm=seq(1,50,0.01)

RRpm<-log(SSpm)+log(114.8393)+ -0.1945079*SSpm
RRpm=exp(RRpm)

y2= log(114.8393)/(-1*-0.1945079)*SSpm + 0
```

I have looked at many different similar questions, but cannot find what I'm looking for.

[R: Finding the intersect of two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521261/r-finding-the-intersect-of-two-lines)

[Which R function can I use to find intersection points of two lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701178/which-r-function-can-i-use-to-find-intersection-points-of-two-lines)

Comment: First why are you adding a 0 to y2? also why are you doing `-1*-0.19...` why not just write `0.19..`? Lastly, you could solve this analytically or numerically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving numerically:

```
val <- optimize(\(SSpm) (exp(log(SSpm)+log(114.8393)-0.1945079*SSpm) - 
           log(114.8393)/0.1945079*SSpm)^2, c(0, 100),tol = 1e-8)

   
SSpm <- val$minimum
RRpm <- exp(log(SSpm)+log(114.8393)+ -0.1945079*SSpm)
RRpm
[1] 194.2721
y2 <- log(114.8393)/(-1*-0.1945079)*SSpm + 0
y2
[1] 194.2721
```